# How to change the Anaconda environment of a jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have created a new Anaconda environnement for Python. I managed to add it has an optional environnement you can choose when you create a new Notebook. Hovewer, I'd like to know how can I change the environnement of an already existing Notebook.

Answer (score 2):

you can change the kernel from `Kernel` option of top menu-bar of `jupyter notebook`

In addition, for different environment the best practice is to use `ipykernel`

in your conda environment install ipykernel by following command:

```
conda install ipykernel
```

name the kernel using:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name other-env --display-name "Python (other-env)"
```

to know more you can follow the link:

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html

Comment: I am not sure to understand what is the point of the hack...

Answer (score 1):

open your `.ipynb` file on your browser. On top, there is `Kernel` tab. You can find your environments under `Change Kernel` part.